# I would like to echo a div

Tags: php, ajax

In $ruta I have the value "imagenes/1.jpg"
If I do that, I display the image

```
<img src="imagenperfil/<?php echo $ruta; ?>" width="250" height="300">
```

but now I have this:

```
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src=''></div>";
```

So in src I would like to put

```
     "imagenperfil/<?php echo $ruta; ?>"
```

I try lots of ways and none works.
thanks a lot! you always solve my all my problems

Comment: None works? Why won't they work its just a string?

Comment: Does this work?

`echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='imagenperfil/{$ruta}'></div>";`

Comment: I tried for example:
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='imagenperfil/<?php echo $ruta; ?>'></div>";
...... and it still doesn't work

Comment: @user1905120 What is `$ruta`?  Where does it get set?  Where is the rest of your code?

Comment: @user1905120 your above codes would work in PHP. So it leads me to think there's an error in your `$ruta`

Comment: @CarlSaldanha, no it will not. You can't run a PHP code block within a PHP code block. Also this has already been solved, so what are you talking about an error in `$ruta`?

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='imagenperfil/$ruta'/></div>" ;
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/6FyFuyT9)

Comment: That was his comment that he tried...?? Why did you copy it and post it as answer -1

Comment: What? Where did you see it as a comment?

Comment: @CarlSaldanha, you are aware there is really only two ways to do this right? So I don't know, statistically you will come up with the same solution. You shouldn't have down-voted this.

Comment: @CarlSaldanha: And you didnt read the part that said `IT DIDNT WORK` :P Because its `NOT` the same thing. Please get your basics clear before down-voting. Here's the demo of whats in the comment http://codepad.org/yfagTvvS

Comment: Okay. Apologies for the downvote. Serious Brainfart here. I decided to just test his line to check for errors and somehow copied your comment by mistake. I'll attribute it to tiredness. Edit the answer and I'll remove the downvote :-D .

Comment: Edit the answer to WHAT? ugh...My answer is correct, it doesn't need any modification.

Comment: @coder1984 Haha yeah I got that. Relax. The only way I can remove a downvote is post a modification. All I meant was if you want me to remove the downvote make a minor grammar change, :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ruta = htmlspecialchars($ruta);
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='imagenperfil/{$ruta}'></div>";
```

Added htmlspecialchars()

Comment: This solution is vulnerable to an XSS attack. Wrap the variable in htmlspecialchars() call.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to do this:

```
echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='"imagenperfil/<?php echo 
$ruta;   ?>"'></div>";
```

then it won't work. You are already in php  and using echo

You can try this:

```
 echo "<div class='tweet_user'><img class='user_img' src='imagenperfil/".$ruta."'></div>";
```